# Why does dbGetQuery take so long when the number of columns is large?

Tags: r, r-dbi, rpostgresql

I am baffled why a simple query takes so long when executed through `RPostgreSQL` but completes almost instantly through another client.  I have a Postgresql database `ncol = 500` and `nrow = 100`. I would like to read the whole database into a dataframe set via the `dbReadTable` function. Failing this, even reading in a single row via `dbGetQuery` would be ok.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con = dbConnect(drv, dbname = "MYDBNAME", host = "MYHOST",
                port = 5432, user = "MYUSER", password = "MYPASSWORD")
before = Sys.time()
res = dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM detailed WHERE project_code='ABCD1234' LIMIT 1;")
after = Sys.time()

before2 = Sys.time()
res2 = dbReadTable(con, "detailed")
after2 = Sys.time()
dbDisconnect(con) # Close PostgreSQL connection
ellapsed = after - before
ellapsed2 = after2-before2
ellapsed
> Time difference of 50.31242 secs
ellapsed2
> Time difference of 50.38002 secs
```

However, I can run `SELECT * FROM detailed;` in 0.5 seconds through another client.

Why does this query take so long to run? What can I do to speed this up?  Could this be a Postgres driver issue with `RPostgreSQL`?

Comment: Have you tried [RPostgres](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgres)? It could be faster than RPostgreSQL.

Comment: Wow, `RPostgres` runs in under one second. I found a [blog post](http://blog.yitang.uk/2016/04/14/compare-rpostgres-and-rpostgresql-package/) illustrating that `RPostgres` runs about 3 times faster than `RPostgreSQL` but in my case when there are many columns, `RPostgres` is more than 50 times faster.